# Android YUV420/NV21 image horizontal flip using reflector on front camera

Tags: android, image, flip

i am trying to flip horizontal an NV21 format image in order to use it on a service [abbysdk](https://github.com/abbyysdk) for page number recognition. I use my Huawei front camera with a small reflector [like Osmo red reflector](https://www.playosmo.com/en/shopping/). The final image direction which i should pass to the servise is like this:
[image that servise wants](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1O09dm51q-4XSi8pwfTegokB-L1gTfr2V)

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542708/camera2-api-convert-yuv420-to-rgb-green-out/33543885) the Single Frame YUV420NV21.If i understood correct the diagram, i need to get each row of the data array in the opposite order. I wrote the code below in order to flip horizontal the data byte array that i am getting from the camera:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
     flippedArray[i * width + j] = data[i * width + (width -j) -1];
     }
 }
```

In order to see the resuls, i converted data and flippedArray in Bitmaps and this is how they look:

[image from reflector](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11vds65VEEmnZDjN9iZoEQof1ZhCxj4N-)

[flipped image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GRtQs2W9hYoPJGlgSm-a83qvEIpHBg4X)

As you can see, the horizontal flip works fine, flippedArray bitmap has the same direction with the one the service wants (i can see the 12 page number as i want), but the flipped image has a green color. As a result, the recognition fails. What am i missing? Is there a way to get the image without the green color?