# Difference Between Camera and Camera2 in Android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I'm building an App which is similar to social media where people can share photos and videos like Instagram. That's why **Camera** is very important for my app. Now camera2 API is confusing me. I want to run my app on API level 11+ . I know camera2 is only available in API level 21+ So, I need to design two APIs one(camera) for older version and second(camera2) for higher version. Problem is that I just started to learn Android and I do not know what is the main difference between these two APIs.

What main features are available in Camera2 API ?
Or Is there any drawback of Old Camera API ?

I need three things in my App.

1- Simple capture photos 
2- Burst pictures (To create GIF Image)
3- Simple video recording.

Which Camera API is good for me ?

Comment: Have a look at this answer and the comments below it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32550373/334402

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The old camera API will work fine for #1 and #3; if you're OK with video-resolution GIFs, you can do #2 as well.

You'll need camera2 (and then devices that support fast, full-resolution capture - see the [BURST_CAPTURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_BURST_CAPTURE) capability, or any device that supports the [FULL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL) hardware level.), if you want bursts at resolutions above ~1080p.

You can probably start with the [CameraView](https://github.com/google/cameraview) unofficial support library, and modify it as needed. It has support for both APIs, selected based on API level of the device.